# Google Sheet Check if any values in a column match part of a cell

Tags: google-sheets, regex

I'm wanting to create a list of strings to search for in Column A. Example "Cafe", "Restaurant", "Shop X"...

Then if a string in another cell (example: "Robert Harris Cafe") **contains** any of the values in column A, I want it to return true.

Similar to `COUNTIF` but but with a `REGEXMATCH`. Count it if it contains any of those values in column A.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). It is unclear whether the desired result should look like `true`, or like `3`, or like `Cafe`, `Shop`, `Service`. Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/168569/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your manually entered desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a true/false result:

```
=0 < counta( 
  iferror( 
    filter( 
      A2:A, 
      search(A2:A, B2) 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

To get a count:

```
=counta( 
  iferror( 
    filter( 
      A2:A, 
      search(A2:A, B2) 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

To list the keywords that match:

```
=filter( 
  A2:A, 
  search(A2:A, B2) 
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Works perfect! True or false is all i was after but those are all great to know!